# Conditional colouring of a geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm analyzing a series that varies around zero. And to see where there are parts of the series with a tendency to be mostly positive or mostly negative I'm plotting a `geom_smooth`. I was wondering if it is possible to have the color of the smooth line be dependent on whether or not it is above or below 0. Below is some code that produces a graph much like what I am trying to create.

```
set.seed(5)
r <- runif(22, max = 5, min = -5)
t <- rep(-5:5,2)
df <- data.frame(r+t,1:22)
colnames(df) <- c("x1","x2")
ggplot(df, aes(x = x2, y = x1)) + geom_hline() + geom_line() + geom_smooth()
```

I considered calculating the smoothed values, adding them to the df and then using a `scale_color_gradient`, but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this in `ggplot` directly.

Comment: What is this line doing? `values(t) <- 1:5`

Comment: Absolutely nothing. removed it now.

Comment: @MarijnStevering When I run your code I got an error: "Error: geom_hline requires the following missing aesthetics: yintercept". You might want to add it (although `geom_hline` isn't needed for your actual problem). +1 for a nice first question.

Comment: @Henrik, For me `geom_hline` works perfectly fine without adding the yintercept. It just seems to default to yintercept = 0 for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the `n` argument in `geom_smooth` to increase "number of points to evaluate smoother at" in order to create some more y values close to zero. Then use `ggplot_build` to grab the smoothed values from the `ggplot` object. These values are used in a `geom_line`, which is added on top of the original plot. Last we overplot the y = 0 values with the `geom_hline`.

```
# basic plot with a larger number of smoothed values
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x2, y = x1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(linetype = "blank", n = 10000)

# grab smoothed values
df2 <- ggplot_build(p)[[1]][[2]][ , c("x", "y")]

# add smoothed values with conditional color
p +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y, color = y > 0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
# loess data
res <- loess.smooth(df$x2, df$x1)
res <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, res))

res$posY <- ifelse(res$y >= 0, res$y, NA)
res$negY <- ifelse(res$y < 0, res$y, NA)

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = x2, y = x1)) + 
  geom_hline() + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(data=res, aes(x = x, y = posY, col = "green")) +
  geom_line(data=res, aes(x = x, y = negY, col = "red")) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: @tonytonov I am aware, don't have time at the moment, thought I might share so the OP can get started, feel free to edit.

Comment: I +1'd, since that'll be enough for rather long and smooth series (and the red-green gaps won't be seen). I'm not sure how to fix these though: ideally one would have to draw another 3-point line that crosses y=0, but that sounds like too much trouble. Maybe there's another approach?

Comment: Definitely is enough to get the general idea across. But ideally would have a continuous line.

Comment: @MarijnStevering try playing with `loess.smooth`, `evaluation = ` argument, bigger numbers will make those gaps smaller... e.g.: this looks ok to me: `res <- loess.smooth(df$x2, df$x1,evaluation = nrow(df) * 10)`