# Different colours for values above / below a linear trend line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to plot a time series with a linear regression line. I would like to have different colours for my time series depending on whether it is above or below the trend line.

Here is a code example to plot the series and the corresponding trend line with different colours for the series  and the line:

```
x  <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2010/1/1"), "years")
y  <- rnorm(length(x),0,10)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', aes(colour = 'Trend'), se = FALSE) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = 'Observation') ) +   
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue","red"))
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908222/conditional-colouring-of-a-geom-smooth

Comment: Estimate the regression, then use the residuals (`sign(model$residuals)`) from the model as a variable to produce color.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I thought about that. The problem with that approach is that the connections between the dots of the time series will have wrong the wrong colours, when one point is above and the other point is below the trend line.

Comment: If you really need to have a line for your time series, I think you'll have to calculate the regression first, add the points where the time series crosses the trendline, and then use @Thomas's suggestion. (And use `group = 1`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got rid of the dates, since they were driving me nuts. Perhaps someone can add a solution for that. Otherwise it seems quite doable, with some basic high school maths.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 2000:2010,
                 y = rnorm(11, 0, 10))
fm <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
co <- coef(fm)
df$under_over <- sign(fm$residuals)
for (i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
  # Get slope and intercept for line segment
  slope <- (df$y[i + 1] - df$y[i]) / (df$x[i + 1] - df$x[i])
  int  <- df$y[i] - slope * df$x[i]
  # find where they would cross
  x <- (co[1] - int) / (slope - co[2])
  y <- slope * x + int
  # if that is in the range of the segment it is a crossing, add to the data
  if (x > df$x[i] & x < df$x[i + 1])
    df <- rbind(df, c(x = x, y = y, under_over = NA))
}
#order by x
df <- df[order(df$x), ]
# find color for intersections
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
  if (is.na(df$under_over[i]))
    df$under_over[i] <- df$under_over[i + 1]

ggplot(df) +
  geom_abline(intercept = co[1], slope = co[2]) +
  geom_path(aes(x, y, col = as.factor(under_over), group = 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]