# Conditional line color in relation to confidence boundaries of a geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `geom_smooth` plot with a confidence interval. On that plot, I have added a secondary line. Something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  # smooth with confidence interval
  geom_smooth(data = mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) +

  # secondary line
  geom_line(aes(x = c(90, 110, 120, 180, 220, 240),
                y = c(100, 120, 130, 150, 160, 170)),
            color = "green", size = 2)
```

[image]

However, I want the color of the second line to depend on whether it falls within the lower and upper limits of the `geom_smooth`:

[image]

How can I achieve such conditional color of a line in relation to a smooth interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit ugly, but it works:

```
# base plot. increase number of points to smooth
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_smooth(n = 2000)

# grab x-values, lower and upper limits
d <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]][ , c("x", "ymin", "ymax")]

# data for the secondary line 
d2 <- data.frame(disp = c(90, 110, 120, 180, 220, 240),
                 hp = c(100, 120, 130, 150, 160, 170))

# interpolate values at the x values from base plot 
l <- approx(d2$disp, d2$hp, xout = d$x)

# create data frame 
d3 <- data.frame(disp = l$x, hp = l$y)

# remove NA values (outside original x)
d <- d[!is.na(d3$hp), ]
d3 <- d3[!is.na(d3$hp), ]

# create indicator: does y-values ("hp") fall in smooth interval?
d3$inside <- NA
d3$inside <- d3$hp < d$ymin | d3$hp > d$ymax

# create group: does line cross smooth limits?
d3$grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(d3$inside) != 0))

# add line to base plot
p + geom_line(data = d3, aes(color = inside, group = grp), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red"), guide = "none") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

---

Related posts which could be useful:

[Different colours for values above / below a linear trend line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502989/different-colours-for-values-above-below-a-linear-trend-line)

Kohske's answer here: [geom_ribbon and when below or above y=0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/Ur9HDvGYihQ)