# geom_smooth line different color based on Y intercept line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, loess

My data is like below. Two column, serial number (SL) and the expression value (log)

```
> df

SL  log
1   1.5
2   -2.5
3   1.0
4   2.5
5   -1.

> ggplot(df, aes(x = SL, y = log)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6, shape = 19, color = "gray") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, linewidth = 0.5, span = 0.09) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", lwd = 0.5)
```

[image]

However, I want to fill the geome_smooth loess line to be filled with red color if it is above the Y=0 intercept line and green color if below Y=0 intercept line. Example figure below.

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like a dupe. Do these approaches work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166859/6851825 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543402/different-colours-of-geom-line-above-and-below-a-specific-value or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789485/different-colors-for-positive-and-negative-values-ggplot2

Comment: ^ those are for geom_line. This question looks more appropriate for conditionally coloring geom_smooth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908222/conditional-colouring-of-a-geom-smooth

Comment: @JonSpring `geom_smooth` doesn't take a `fill` argument. And I am not sure those solutions would work for `stat_smooth`.

Comment: Good points. I think doable by extracting the loess shape and then using a solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72976474/6851825

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your answers. Following code worked perfectly:

```
smoothed_values <- predict(loess(log ~ SL, data = df, span = 0.09)) 
fill_color <- ifelse(smoothed_values >= 0, "red", "green")

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = SL, y = log)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6, shape = 19, color = "gray") +
  ggbraid::geom_braid(aes(SL, ymin = 0, ymax = smoothed_values, fill = fill_color), 
                      alpha = 0.5, lwd = 0.5, color = "gray3") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lwd = 0.25, color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Gene Order", y = "logFC") +
  scale_fill_identity(name = "Gene Expression", 
                      labels = c("Down", "Up"), guide = "legend", 
                      breaks = c("green", "red"), limits = c("green", "red")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-5, 5, by = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a super simple answer, since you first need to extract the loess line to use it with geom_area (which can't vary in fill) or geom_ribbon (which won't automatically separate regions of the same sign).

I like using `ggbraid` once we've extracted the loess line, as it will make a nice clean interpolation with separate fill regions.

Given some fake data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, 
                 y = sin(seq(0,8, length.out = 100)) + sin(1:100))
```

We could make a plot and extract the loess curve using the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32911114/6851825):

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
df2 <- ggplot_build(p)[[1]][[2]][,c("x","y")]
```

Then we have a slightly tricky problem involving interpolation, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135962/how-to-fill-with-different-colors-between-two-lines-originally-fill-geom-poly) and [here](https://github.com/nsgrantham/ggbraid). One simple solution is to use the `ggbraid` package, which identifies the exact crossing points and cleanly separates the fill areas.

```
# using ggbraid from remotes::install_github("nsgrantham/ggbraid")
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  ggbraid::stat_braid(aes(x, ymin = 0, ymax = y, fill = y < 0),
                      data = df2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = df2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: "which can't vary in fill". Not entirely accurate, it cannot vary within the same group. Also, ggbraid does calculate the crossing points accurately, but also would smooth the data beyond what we'd get from geom_smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach by interpolating the values between the rows where `sign(y)` changes, then creating two groups for `stat_smooth` data, one for positive and one for negative values, and finally recreating the plot with the new data.

First, we need to make a plot with the smoothed data.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
# library(tidyr) ## we only need tidyr::fill
```

```r
## example dataset
set.seed(123)
df.ex <- data.frame(s = 1:600, l = round(rnorm(600, sd = 2), 1))

## creating the first plot with stat_smooth; same fill color for + & -
ggplot(df.ex, aes(x = s, y = l)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6, shape = 19, color = "gray") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", lwd = 0.5) +
  stat_smooth(method = "loess", geom = "area", fill = "pink",
              se = FALSE, linewidth = 0.5, span = 0.09, 
              color = "blue",  alpha = 0.8) -> p; p
```

[image]

Then we extract the "smoothed data" from `ggplot2` object, will find the `x` coordinates of where `geom_smooth` goes from positive `y` to negative or vice versa (i.e. `y == 0`), and will modify the data for the final plot.

```r
## ggplot build to extract the smooth data
q <- ggplot_build(p)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'

smdat <- copy(q[[1]][[3]])
setDT(smdat)

## set the fill colors and group for negative and positive values
smdat[ , group := ifelse(y > 0 , 1, 2)][, fill := ifelse(y < 0 , "green", "red")]

## interpolation; taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137211/6461462
smdat_grp <- smdat[ , {
  ix = .I[c(FALSE, abs(diff(sign(smdat$y))) == 2)]
  if(length(ix)){
    pred_x = sapply(ix, function(i) approx(x = y[c(i-1, i)], 
                                           y = x[c(i-1, i)], xout = 0)$y)
    rbindlist(.(.SD, data.table(x = pred_x, y = 0, group = 1, ymax = 0),
                     data.table(x = pred_x, y = 0, group = 2, ymax = 0)), 
              fill = TRUE)} else .SD}][order(x)]

## filling the NA values in the remaining columns 
lapply(split(smdat_grp, smdat_grp$group), \(dat) 
       tidyr::fill(dat, everything(), .direction = "downup")) |> 
    rbindlist() |> 
    as.data.frame() -> q[[1]][[3]]

## plot the modified ggplot
pq <- ggplot_gtable(q)

plot(pq)
```

[image]

As you can see, using `ggbraid::geom_braid` or `ggbraid::stat_braid`, although very close, gives us slightly different results from what we get from `stat_smooth`/`geom_smooth`.

```r
smoothed_values <- predict(loess(l ~ s, data = df.ex, span = 0.09)) 
fill_color <- ifelse(smoothed_values >= 0, "red", "green")

ggplot(df.ex, aes(x = s, y = l)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6, shape = 19, color = "gray") +
  
  ggbraid::geom_braid(aes(s, ymin = 0, ymax = smoothed_values, fill = fill_color), 
                      alpha = 0.5, lwd = 0.5, color = "gray3") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lwd = 0.25, color = "black") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, linewidth = 1, span = 0.09) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 1)) ## zoom to see the difference
#> `geom_braid()` using method = 'line'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>